# Are there tools can view the data of the memory of the IE browser, such as javascript data?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-7

Recently wrote some JavaScript code, but there has been a memory leak in IE7.Are there tools  can view the IE7 JavaScript data in memory? very thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use John Resig profile tracer it does the job really well http://ejohn.org/blog/deep-tracing-of-internet-explorer/